# PHP fileupload error 6

Tags: php, apache

my PHP upload fails with an `error:6` but I don't know why. I checked all the parameters which are descriped in some stackoverflow posts, but without a soulution.

[image: Header of the Request]

As you see, I just get an error 6.
All the values (TMP_DIR, SYS_TMP_DIR) are set, but it does not work.

[image: Overview FirePHP logs]

The apache user has the permission to access `/tmp` on the server.

Is there an issue I have overlooked?

```
require_once '../libs/firephp-core-0.4.0/lib/FirePHPCore/fb.php';
$tmp = getcwd()."/tmp";

ini_set('open_basedir', $tmp);
ini_set('upload_tmp_dir',$tmp);

ob_start();
fb($_FILES, "FILES");
fb(ini_get('open_basedir'), 'OPEN_BASEDIR');
$tmp_dir = ini_get('upload_tmp_dir') ? ini_get('upload_tmp_dir') : sys_get_temp_dir();
fb($tmp_dir, "TMP_DIR");
fb(sys_get_temp_dir(), "SYS-TMP-DIR");

$uploaddir =  getcwd()."/uploads/";
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename.basename($_FILES['x0']['name']);
fb($uploadfile, 'FILE PATH');
fb(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['x0']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile), "MOVE RESULT");
```

Comment: What does your http servers error log file reveal?

Comment: it means Missing a temporary folder make sure it is writable. see here http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir

Comment: This is the log-entry :  `PHP Warning:  File upload error - unable to create a temporary file in Unknown on line 0, referer: http://mobile.dev.local/www/ ` and the folder has permission `777`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `upload_tmp_dir` configuration must be set in the `php.ini` file so that it is available before the script is running. When the script starts to run the file is already uploaded (or not in case of an error).

> ini_set('upload_tmp_dir',$tmp);

I see that you try to set `upload_tmp_dir` but that statement is executed to late. Go to `php.ini` and set it there:

```
upload_tmp_dir = /tmp
```

Comment: is there a was to define this before the upload starts to run?

Comment: No, the only place where you can 'define' it is in the php.ini file

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that your temp variable not working correctly. 
After this file from php http://php.net/manual/de/features.file-upload.errors.php the error says Missing a temporary folder

Answer (score 0):

In my case I didn't have `tmp` directory in the proper location. I have in the root as `/tmp/` but it is not what Apache looking for.
So check `php.ini` and make sure that the specified directory exist as mentioned for `sys_temp_dir`.

> sys_temp_dir  /var/www/wms/tmp

[image]

Answer (score -1):

i solved my problem
on XAMPP environment

execute this commant to know if your file is alright

```
<link to php> -i | grep "Loaded Configuration File"
```

[the error in php.ini](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPG9q.png)

and then return a error so that's why can't figure out where was my **upload_tmp_dir**

*I hope to help someone ‍*